# For any real square matrix which are correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

For any real square matrix $M$ let $\lambda^+(M)$ be the number of positive eigenvalues of $M$ counting multiplicity. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and $Q$ be an $n\times n$ real invertible matrix. Then which are correct?

1. Rank $(A)$ = Rank $Q^TAQ$
2. Rank $(A)$ = Rank $Q^{-1}AQ$
3. $\lambda^+(A)$ = $\lambda^+(Q^TAQ)$
4. $\lambda^+(A)$ = $\lambda^+(Q^{-1}AQ)$

I can see 2 is correct but what about the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) is true and is in fact a consequence of the more general rule
${\sf rank}(PAQ)={\sf rank}(A)$ whenever $P$ and $Q$ are invertible.

(4) is also true because the eigenvalues of $Q^{-1}AQ$ are exactly
the eigenvalues of $A$ (indeed, $v$ is an eigenvector of $Q^{-1}AQ$
iff $Qv$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and the eigenvalue is the same).

(3) is a consequence of Sylvester’s law of inertia as pointed out in
user44197's answer.

Comment: So all four are correct?

Comment: @user113578 Yes.

Comment: (1)${\sf rank}(PAQ)={\sf rank}(A)$ how does the statement true

Comment: can you point out reference. please help me.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

2, 4) is similarity transformation, so $\cdots$

3) is the law of inertia. If you have not come across it, you should read it up

1) also follows from law of inertia

Wikipedia Article on [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)